# Transpose rank value into new columns

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, transpose

I have dataframe ranking patientid and encounter. I'm stuck on how to transpose (?) it so I have one row per patientid, with 3 columns: ['patientid', 'phq1_check', 'phq4_check]. So just patientid, and the 1st and 4th visits.

```
PHQ['Rank'] = PHQ.sort_values((['patientid','encounter'])
                     .groupby(['patientid'])['encounter'] 
                     .rank(method='min').astype(int))
```

[image]

This is the output in sql that I can't seem to reproduce

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
PHQ = PHQ.pivot(index='patientid', columns='Rank', values='encounter').reset_index()
PHQ = PHQ.loc[:, ['patientid', 1, 4]]
```